# Texshop not compiling after Mac update to sierra 10.12.4

Tags: texshop

After I updated my Mac yesterday, TeXshop is not compiling some of my documents anymore. This is the case especially for `beamer-class` documents where I worked with `include` to combine separated parts in to one master document. TeXshop opens normal documents like Articles and so on and also compiles these ones, but the `beamer-class`, which I need to continue my works, is not running, as explained above.

Did someone had the same problems and already came up with a solution that worked?

Comment: This is not really enough information to go on. What does  "not compile" mean? Do you get errors? If so, what are they? If you create a new `beamer` document, does it work? If not, what error do you get?  If it does then the problem is not with `beamer` but with your particular documents.

Comment: Can you give a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for a document which does not work?