# TeXShop and Mac preview crashing - is it fixed in the macOS 10.12.5?

Tags: preview, macos

In April, there was a bug in PDFKit in macOS 10.12.4 that caused a crash while using TeXshop (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362047/texshop-and-mac-preview-crashing-when-opening-latex-beamer-built-pdfs%20/)).

Herb Schulz wrote that Apple knows this and is working on a solution.

I wanted to ask if this bug is fixed in macOS 10.12.5?

And I know that I can fix this problem by deleting the `.pdf`-file and comment out `\usepackage{pstricks}` but I have many old `.tex`-documents which I cannot open and it is very annoying to do this for every file.

Comment: Sorry, PDFKit is not fixed in 10.12.5. However one of the package combinations that could produce a PDF that crashed PDFKit has been fixed.